# Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 8

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker, tflite, custom-training

**Im using sagemaker to train the data it has pretrained model
** -- **“tensorflow-od1-ssd-resnet50-v1-fpn-640x640-coco17-tpu-8”**

**For Training:
**
Create the SageMaker model instance. Note that we need to pass Predictor class when we deploy model through Model class,
for being able to run inference through the sagemaker API.

```
model = Model(
image_uri=deploy_image_uri,
source_dir=deploy_source_uri,
model_data=base_model_uri,
entry_point=“inference.py”,
role=aws_role,
predictor_cls=Predictor,
name=endpoint_name,
)
```

## deploy the Model.

```
base_model_predictor = model.deploy(
initial_instance_count=1,
instance_type=inference_instance_type,
endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
)
```

Load the saved model

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_dir)
```

Convert the model to a TFLite model

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Save the TFLite model to disk

```
with open(tflite_model_file, ‘wb’) as f:
f.write(tflite_model)
```

I trained and converting it to .tflite file and using it my swift application it got an error
Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 8

Im trying to detect my object it failed

Comment: The Model object in the SageMaker SDK is used for defining the SageMaker Model parameters that will be used for deployment not training. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: After deploying 
1. I downloaded model.tar.gz into local
2. Extract that model.tar.gz file
3. Convert that saved_model.pb to .tflite 
4. Using that .tflite in my swift application 
By using Detector from "TensorFlowLiteTaskVision"
      
detector = try ObjectDetector.detector(options: options)

while predicting it shows an error 
Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 8

Comment: take a look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47595)

Comment: Yeah i searched i dont know where my issue was?